# npm err! enoent this is related to npm not being able to find a file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

So i have created a react app, im pretty new at this, and it has already opened in the past, but now i run npm start and this appears:

```
PS C:\Users\maxim\.vscode\extensions\second react> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\maxim\.vscode\extensions\second react/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\maxim\.vscode\extensions\second react\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\maxim\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-23T22_46_45_545Z-debug-0.log     
PS C:\Users\maxim\.vscode\extensions\second react>
```

what is my error, what do i do? How can i prevent this from ever happening?

Comment: It seems you are not inside the react project, otherwise you would find the package.json
Just be sure to run `npm start` inside the correct directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first reason might be that you aren't in the project directory (where the package.json is located). So navigate with:
`cd "project directory inside these quotes"`.
Then you run "npm start" in your terminal.

If this is not the reason, most probably, it might be because you have a dependency that doesn’t install correctly. To solve this issue:

1. Clean your npm cache: `npm cache clean --force`
2. Delete node modules and package-lock.json (Not package.json! But package-lock.json. This auto re-generates after starting the project, so don't worry.
3. Install dependencies again: `npm install` and then start the project from the project directory `npm start`

Comment: It's definitely not the second reason