# why I am getting this error, what should i do?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

The error show in terminal

```
D:\\Project\>npx create-react-app max

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall lstat

npm ERR! path C:\\Users\\preet\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\\Users\\preet\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\preet\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\\_logs\\2023-07-19T12_38_31_048Z-debug-0.log
```

Pls give the solution to fix this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm err! enoent this is related to npm not being able to find a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74553802/npm-err-enoent-this-is-related-to-npm-not-being-able-to-find-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `npm` installed on your system by running

```
npm --version
```

And install the latest version

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands in sequential order. Hope it will help you.

```
npm install -g create-react-app    
npx create-react-app max     
cd max      
npm start
```